# Acceder a un archivo de configuración de otro proyecto desde una clase c#

Tags: c#, xml

Tengo dos proyectos, **proyect1** y **proyect2** y en el **proyect1** tengo un **app.config** que necesito acceder desde una clase que tengo en el **proyect2**

Codigo del app.config del proyect1

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
       <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="RutaManualServicio" value="@\\SALA2-PC25\Carpeta compartida 
        (Manuales)"/>
        <add key="RutaManualOperador" value="@\\SALA2-PC25\Carpeta compartida 
        (Manuales)"/>
        <add key="RutaMantenimiento" value="May 5, 2014"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Trabajo con visual studio community 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aqui te dejo un ejemplo de clase que esta creada en un proyecto de tipo Biblioteca de clases que lee la configuración del proyecto principal(por ejemplo de tipo winform)

```
 public class ClaseOtroProyecto
{
   public  ClaseOtroProyecto()
   {
       var url =ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RutaManualServicio"].ToString();
       if (url != null)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(url);
       }
   }
}
```

Un saludo